# Why does Digicert have so many Root Certificates? Which one is right for me?

Tags: tls, x.509

I'm trying to add a system root certificate to a container that doesn't have any. Digicert is a CA that I've used before, but I've never had to add a root certificate to my system before.

Then I noticed that Digicert has loads of root certificates to choose from. Which one is right for me? Why are there so many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one is right for me?

This depends on your specific but unknown use case. You need to add a new root certificate only if you need to verify certificates which were directly or indirectly issued by a yet untrusted root certificate.

Note that adding a root certificate does not help in the common case of a misconfigured server which fails to send the intermediate certificate.

> Why are there so many?

Some of these root CA come from acquisitions of other CA like CyberTrust. Some are used for different purposes - like issuing normal certificates vs. issuing EV certificates. Some have different types of keys, i.e. RSA vs. ECDSA.